# Showing how many rows are grouped into the same field

Tags: php, mysql

The query below shows a list of all "zip"s in a MySQL table.  It groups rows that have the same "zip".

How could I create a new variable that shows how many rows share each "zip"?

```
$query2 = "select zip from submission
GROUP BY zip    
order by zip asc";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`COUNT(*)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) to your select list:

```sql
SELECT zip, COUNT(*) FROM submission GROUP BY zip ORDER BY zip ASC
```